# Run a .py file without Python installed using .bat

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file to run my .py file on Windows without Python installed, mainly so I can send my programs to friends. So in my .bat file I would like to:

Change to the current working directory. (So it runs wherever the file is)
Change directory to a folder inside that directory.
Run a python file without my friends having to install python themselves.

Comment: why not use `pyinstaller` or `cx_freeze`?

Comment: 1. Fine. 2. Fine. 3. Requires you to implement your own Python interpreter in batch, so... [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/248731)?

Comment: Kinda like running an OS without installing it...it doesn't make sense.  You will have to either install python or create an execuatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.py2exe.org/ which will convert you python code to a executable windows program that you can send to your friends.

Answer (score 7):

> Run a .py file without Python installed using .bat

You can't run a Python script using a batch command without Python being installed. You can compile an executable with [Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (which bundles an entire Python interpreter with your script), or convert a subset of Python to C++ with [shedskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shed_Skin), which can then be compiled to an executable. You could also issue a shell command to install Python if it's not already installed and the user has internet.

But doing exactly what you asked is impossible.